# Display related data from table in Laravel Blade

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

How can I retrieve data from my respondent table when it has a one-to-one relationship with the ages table, sexes table, diseases table, and vaccines table?

I want to display within my table.blade.php file the contents in my respondent table, but when I tried to display the age, sex, disease, and vaccine, it only displayed its ID and not its content from their individual tables.

**Respondent schema**

```
public function up(): void
{
    Schema::create('respondents', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->unsignedInteger('id_purok');
        $table->unsignedInteger('id_household');
        $table->unsignedInteger('id_age');
        $table->unsignedInteger('id_sex');
        $table->unsignedInteger('id_marital_status');
        $table->unsignedInteger('id_means_of_living');
        $table->unsignedInteger('id_educational_attainment');
        $table->unsignedInteger('id_physical_condition');
        $table->unsignedInteger('id_disease');
        $table->unsignedInteger('id_vacinne');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('id_purok')->references('id')->on('puroks');
        $table->foreign('id_household')->references('id')->on('household_heads');
        $table->foreign('id_age')->references('id')->on('ages');
        $table->foreign('id_sex')->references('id')->on('sexes');
        $table->foreign('id_marital_status')->references('id')->on('marital_statuses');
        $table->foreign('id_means_of_living')->references('id')->on('means_of_livings');
        $table->foreign('id_educational_attainment')->references('id')->on('educational_attainments');$table->foreign('id_physical_condition')->references('id')->on('physical_conditions');
        $table->foreign('id_disease')->references('id')->on('diseases');
        $table->foreign('id_vacinne')->references('id')->on('vaccines');
    });
}
```

**Ages table**

```
public function up(): void
{
    Schema::create('ages', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('age');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**Sexes table**

```
public function up(): void
{
    Schema::create('sexes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('sex');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**Diseases table**

```
public function up(): void
{
    Schema::create('diseases', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('disease');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**Vaccines table**

```
public function up(): void
{
    Schema::create('vaccines', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('vaccine');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**Respondent controller**

```
public function index()
{
    $respondents = Respondent::all();
    $households = HouseholdHead::all();
    $puroks = Purok::all();
    $diseases = Disease::all();
    $vaccines = Vaccine::all();

    return view('respondent_table', compact('respondents', 'households', 'puroks', 'diseases', 'vaccines'));
}
```

**Respondent model**

```
class Respondent extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function vaccine()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Vaccine::class);
    }

    public function disease()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Disease::class);
    }

    public function age()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Age::class);
    }

    public function sex()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Sex::class);
    }  
}
```

**table.blade.php**

```
<table class="table table-striped " id="dataTable">
    </div>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Surename</th>
        <th>Purok</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Sex</th>
        <th>Disease</th>
        <th>Vaccine</th>
        <th>Physical Condition</th>
        <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach ($respondents as $respondent)
        <tr>
            <td> {{$respondent->name}} </td>
            <td> {{$respondent->id_purok}} </td>
            <td> {{$respondent->id_age}} </td>
            <td> {{$respondent->id_sex}} </td>
            <td> {{$respondent->id_disease}} </td>
            <td> {{$respondent->id_vacinne}} </td>
            <td> {{$respondent->id_physical_condition}} </td>
            <td> {{$respondent->created_at}} </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

First update your controller.

```
public function index()
{
    $respondents = Respondent::with('age', 'sex', 'disease', 'vaccine')->get();
    $households = HouseholdHead::all();
    $puroks = Purok::all();
    $diseases = Disease::all();
    $vaccines = Vaccine::all();

    return view('respondent_table', compact('respondents', 'households', 'puroks', 'diseases', 'vaccines'));
}
```

You can modify your `table.blade.php` file to display the content from related tables.

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="dataTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Surname</th>
            <th>Purok</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Sex</th>
            <th>Disease</th>
            <th>Vaccine</th>
            <th>Physical Condition</th>
            <th>Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach ($respondents as $respondent)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $respondent->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $respondent->purok->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $respondent->age->age }}</td>
            <td>{{ $respondent->sex->sex }}</td>
            <td>{{ $respondent->disease->disease }}</td>
            <td>{{ $respondent->vaccine->vaccine }}</td>
            <td>{{ $respondent->physical_condition }}</td>
            <td>{{ $respondent->created_at }}</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Also, make sure the relationships are correctly defined in your Respondent model

```
class Respondent extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function vaccine()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Vaccine::class, 'id_vacinne');
    }

    public function disease()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Disease::class, 'id_disease');
    }

    public function age()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Age::class, 'id_age');
    }

    public function sex()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Sex::class, 'id_sex');
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried : <td > {{$respondent->id_age->age}} </td> but it says Attempt to read property "age" on int, but when i tried <td > {{$respondent->age->id_age}} </td> it says Attempt to read property "id_age" on null

Comment: The age property should be accessed using the age() relationship, not through 'id_age'.

Comment: but when i tried <td > {{$respondent->age->age}} </td> and <td > {{$respondent->sex->sex}} </td> it says Attempt to read property "age" on null

Comment: <td>{{ optional($respondent->age)->age }}</td>
<td>{{ optional($respondent->sex)->sex }}</td>